# Angular 9 grouping items by date

Tags: angular, sorting, grouping

I need to group my json objects by date of creation in my Angular ToDo app, and I can't figure out how to make it work. The pipes don't work :/ The result should be like :

Today
do homework / 27.11.2019
go for a run/  27.11.2019

Yesterday
eat tomato / 26.11.2019
drink milk / 26.11.2019

Older tasks
task1 / 20.11.2019
task2 / 20.11.2019
etc

The html template looks like this:

```
    <div class="edit-popup" *ngIf="show">
      <input type="text" name="" class="edit-item" value="{{value}}" #item>
      <button class="btn-update" (click)="update(item.value)">Update</button>
    </div>

    <input type="text" name="" class="item" #item>
    <button class="btn-add-item" (click)="create(item.value)">Add</button>

    <ul>

        <li *ngFor="let item of mockData" >

        <span [ngClass]="{'done': item.done}" >{{item.title}} {{item.date | date: 'shortDate'}} </span>
        <button (click)="remove(item.id)">Delete</button>
        <button (click)="edit(item.id, item.title)">Edit</button>
        <button (click)="setTaskComplete(item.id)">Complete</button>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and this is the data:

```
    "id": "1",
    "title": "This is title",
    "done": false,
    "date": "2019-11-26T11:46:18Z"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "This is title",
    "done": true,
    "date": "2019-11-26T11:46:18Z"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "This is title",
    "done": false,
    "date": "2017-11-26T11:46:18Z"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "title": "This is title",
    "done": false,
    "date": "2018-11-22T11:46:18Z"
}]
```

and here is the component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import  *  as  data  from  '../data.json';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tasks',
  templateUrl: './tasks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tasks.component.css']
})
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {

  mockData: any  = (data  as  any).default;

  show: boolean = false;
  value: string;
  id: number;


  constructor() {}


  remove(id) {
    this.mockData = this.mockData.filter(item => {
      if (item.id !== id) {
        return item;
      }
    });
  }

  create(item) {
    this.mockData.push({
      id: Date.now(),
      title: item,
      done: false,
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  update(title) {
    this.mockData.map(item => {
      if (item.id === this.id) {
        item['title'] = title;
      }
    });

    this.show = false;
  }

  edit(id, title) {
    this.show = true;
    this.value = title;
    this.id = id;
  }

  setTaskComplete(id) {
    this.mockData.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        item['done'] = true;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: What pipe does not work? I don't see any pipe that groups data in your code. In addition, Angular recommends to group data in a component: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: I've tried the orderBy pipe and also ngIf to show only the objects where item.date == 26/11/19 but for some reason neither works. The most important is that the results need to be grouped into days, not only sorted asc or desc.

Comment: Grouping of data should be done in component rather than HTML